# Pandas Dataframe fill column with first value of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a df like this:

```
   Group  Col1  Col2  Col3
0      A   NaN   NaN   NaN
1      A    11   NaN   NaN
2      A    11    52     3
3      A    11    52     3
4      B   NaN   NaN   NaN
5      B   NaN   NaN    18
6      B   NaN     2    18
7      B    20     2    18
8      B    20     2    18
9      C   NaN   NaN   NaN
10     C   NaN   NaN   NaN
11     C   NaN   202   NaN
12     C   NaN   202   NaN
13     C   NaN   202     6
14     C   NaN   202     6
```

and I would like to construct the 'Value' column based on the 'Group' column, and the first values of columns Col1, Col2 and Col3 at the same time.  The desired df would be like this:

```
   Group  Col1  Col2  Col3  Value
0      A   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
1      A    11   NaN   NaN     11  # first value in Col1
2      A    11    52     3     11
3      A    11    52     3     11
4      B   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
5      B   NaN   NaN    18     18  # first value in Col3
6      B   NaN     2    18     18
7      B    20     2    18     18
8      B    20     2    18     18
9      C   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
10     C   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
11     C   NaN   202   NaN    202  # first value in Col2
12     C   NaN   202   NaN    202
13     C   NaN   202     6    202
14     C   NaN   202     6    202
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and taking the `first` valid value within each group:

```
s = slice('Col1','Col3')
df['Value'] = (df.loc[:,s]
                .ffill(1)
                .groupby(df.Group)
                .transform('first').Col3
                .where(df.loc[:,s].any(1)))
```

---

```
print(df)

    Group  Col1   Col2  Col3  Value
0      A   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
1      A  11.0    NaN   NaN   11.0
2      A  11.0   52.0   3.0   11.0
3      A  11.0   52.0   3.0   11.0
4      B   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
5      B   NaN    NaN  18.0   18.0
6      B   NaN    2.0  18.0   18.0
7      B  20.0    2.0  18.0   18.0
8      B  20.0    2.0  18.0   18.0
9      C   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
10     C   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
11     C   NaN  202.0   NaN  202.0
12     C   NaN  202.0   NaN  202.0
13     C   NaN  202.0   6.0  202.0
14     C   NaN  202.0   6.0  202.0
​
```